# PHP - Unable to set session_id()

Tags: php, session

I'm creating a `login.php` and `post.php` for my project. I'm passing the `session_id` of `login.php` to my java application and then passing the `session_id` to `post.php` using POST method.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {

    $usr=$_POST['usr'];
    $passwd=$_POST['pass'];

    //connecting to my db and checking for username and password.
    // After match occurs,           

    $_SESSION['login_user']=$usr;
    echo session_id();
    }

?>
```

post.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$sid = $_POST['sid'];
session_id($sid);
echo session_id();
?>
```

I'm getting error like this when I give post request to `post.php`,

> Warning: Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp)in Unknown on line 0

I checked,

- the permission of `/tmp` directory. It is writable.
- `$sid` in `post.php`. It contains the `session_id` of `login.php`.
- `$sid` contains no illegal characters.
- Also this error is not displayed when I tried to set custom `session_id`like this in `post.php`

  session_id("12345abcdedfg");

From what I observed, this error is being displayed only when I set a session_id which is a session_id some other php file which is just now requested, i.e when session is active.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use `session_id(uniqid());` because it can return characters that are not acceptable as session IDs (remember, sessions are saved as files with the same name as the session)

Comment: @Machavity I don't know about it. I worked for me when I used. But that's not what I'm asking.. Okay let me edit it, so nobody will say that again..